# ADFS is able to load uninstalled DLL from GAC (global application cache)

Tags: windows, adfs, gac

I am using `gacutil` to ***install / uninstall*** a `.dll` file on Windows Server. When I run the

`sh Register-AdfsAuthenticationProvider  -TypeName "MFAadapter.MyAdapter, MFAadapter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d8adf87d2f36ce35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" -Name "MyADFS"`

command it registers the DLL successfully in ADFS. How is this possible?

*Expected Result:*

ADFS throws an Exception stating that dll is missing

Answer (score -1):

follow the documentation provided from the Microsoft 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool